Connection with fingerprint time attendance via Socket
Currently, I am developing a web system, mainly using PHP, and in one of its parts, I realized it would be interesting to create a way for the system to connect to the company's time clock, read-only, to facilitate data import for internal reports. So, I started creating some PHP code and managed to connect to the device (I think), but when I inserted the commands, I couldn't interpret the response sent by the equipment. I'm having trouble with that. If anyone knows a way to interpret this information (it seems to be coming in some sort of corrupted ASCII code, I'm not sure what it is) or has a better alternative than using a socket or a better way to do this, it would be of great help.

<?php
$host = 'equipment IP connected to the network'; // IP of the Henry Hexa C time clock
$port = 80; // Default communication port

// Attempts to create the socket
$socket = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$socket) {
    // Error message if the connection fails
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to the time clock. $errstr ($errno)";
} else {
    // Success message when the connection is established
    echo "Successfully connected to the time clock at IP $host and port $port.<br>";

    // Example of sending the collection command
    $comando = "come here command \r\n";
    fwrite($socket, $comando);

    // Receive the response from the time clock
    echo "Receiving data from the time clock:<br>";
    while (!feof($socket)) {
        echo fgets($socket, 128) . "<br>";
    }

    // Close the socket
    fclose($socket);
    echo "Connection successfully closed.";
}
?>


I am having trouble reading data from a time clock using a socket connection in PHP, and I need help with this.

If anyone knows a way to interpret this information...you haven't shared any sample data or information, or told us anything meaningful about the device. So what do you expect us to tell you? Please [edit] the question. Before you post it again, read it through as if you are someone who's never seen anything about your situation before, and see if you think they would understand what is happening in enough detail to be able to suggest anything useful.

Does the device have any documentation about how to integrate with it, or what protocol it uses? That would be an obvious place to start. What made you try using raw sockets in the first place?
